# Unable to locate package ros groovy desktop full

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am currently trying to install the Groovy ROS onto Ubuntu 13.04 desktop i386 using virtual box.

I have been following all the steps however when I get to the install part I keep getting this error message

unable to locate package ros groovy desktop full

can someone please advise me as to where or what I might have missed

Thanks in advance Charly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65904/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-desktop-full/) by [charly79](https://answers.ros.org/users/5232/charly79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-06-25**:
Have you execute `sudo apt-get update` ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-25**:
Please include the full error message with copy and paste, as well as the commands you are attempting.

**Comment by [charly79](https://answers.ros.org/users/5232/charly79/) on 2013-06-25**:
yes I did the update, I will try to copy and paste the error tomorrow as its all installed on my work machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does groovy even support 13.04/raring?

According to joq's answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/56556/groovy-on-raring/), and the groovy page [here](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy), that's waiting for Hydro.

Given that you're running in a virtual machine anyways, I'd strongly recommend using Ubuntu 12.04 instead.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charly79](https://answers.ros.org/users/5232/charly79/) on 2013-06-25**:
Thank you this is all very new to me, I was following a guide with links that kept taking me to version 13.04. I shall try again tomorrow with 12.04. So far I am not enjoying the whole Linux experience let hope it improves.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-25**:
If you're switching to linux to learn this you'll need to be a little bit patient to learn both at once.